# How to implement a python thread pool to test for network connectivity?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to implement a Python (2.6.x/2.7.x) thread pool that would check for network connectivity(ping or whatever), the entire pool threads must be killed/terminated when the check is successful.

So I am thinking of creating a pool of, let's say, 10 worker threads. If any one of them is successful in pinging, the main thread should terminate all the rest.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Right now, the question is too broad and possible answer cannot address a particular problem. In case you have some *concrete* issue, not "how do I implement XXX - describe it, otherwise this question will be closed most likely.

Comment: My question is specific enough already

Comment: Well, whether or not to listen to my advice - is up to you.

Comment: @SoumyadipDM Is that you want `ping` to multiple ip's or a single ip?

Comment: @gsb-eng possibly around 2000 ips. Thing is I don't want to wait until all 2000 ips are checked, but to stop all running threads at the moment I find one of the ips are pinging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a compilable code, this is just to give you and idea how to make threads communicate..

Inter process or threads communication happens through `queues` or `pipes` and some other ways..here I'm using `queues` for communication.

It works like this.. I'll send ip addresses in `in_queue` and add response to `out_queue`, my  main `thread` monitors `out_queue` and if it gets desired result, it marks all the threads to `terminate`.

Below is the `pinger` thread definition..

```
import threading

from Queue import Queue, Empty

# A thread that pings ip.
class Pinger(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, kwargs=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.stop_pinging = False

    def run(self):
        ip_queue = self.kwargs.get('in_queue')
        out_queue = self.kwargs.get('out_queue')
        while not self.stop_pinging:
            try:
                data = ip_quque.get(timeout=1)
                ping_status = ping(data)

                # This is pseudo code, you've to takecare of
                # your own ping.
                if ping_status:
                    out_queue.put('success')
                    # you can even break here if you don't want to
                    # continue after one success
                else:
                    out_queue.put('failure')
                if ip_queue.empty()
                    break
            except Empty, e:
                pass
```

Here is the main thread block..

```
# Create the shared queue and launch both thread pools
in_queue = Queue()
out_queue = Queue()

ip_list = ['ip1', 'ip2', '....']
# This is to add all the ips to the queue or you can
# customize to add through some producer way.
for ip in ip_list:
    in_queue.put(ip)

pingerer_pool = []

for i in xrange(1, 10):
    pingerer_worker = Pinger(kwargs={'in_queue': in_queue, 'out_queue': out_queue}, name=str(i))
    pingerer_pool.append(pinger_worker)
    pingerer_worker.start()

while 1:
    if out_queue.get() == 'success':
        for pinger in pinger_pool:
            pinger_worker.stop_pinging = True

        break
```

Note: This is a pseudo code, you should make this workable as you like.